# Mobile App Connecting to my local web server

Tags: iphone, local

Looking for assistance on why I can access my local web server when I'm on my wireless network but not from my mobile phone (when not connected to wifi).  I have tried using dyndns, wan ip, regular ip address but I can't see to grasp what I should be doing.  I have my MAMP server running and php on 8888 for which the appropriate php file runs successfully when I'm logged into my network.  I'm just trying to access this now from the public domain and I'm not sure what i need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your router to forward the external requests to the correct internal computer & port.

I.e. any external requests to port 8888 should be forwarded to your computer's IP address on port 8888. Most routers will have this option in the admin panel somewhere.

[EDIT]

This website might be able to help - http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm